# Facebook get user_friends works only with test users

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop an android app with a Facebook login. I implemented the login with Facebook button and gave a user_friends permission.
I tried it with Facebook test users and the Facebook API explorer and it seems to work, but when I created 2 real Facebook account link them as friends and add them as testers to my app it returned an empty [] every time. (i logged in to my app with both users).

this is the response I get when I use real users:
'''Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":2}}, error: null''''

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Did both of those accounts grant the `user_friends` permission?